# Change opacity of the element when scroll reach the end of the Section

Tags: jquery, css

Let's say i have a header section that has 500px height, so now i want to change the opacity of the logo with scroll when we reach to the bottom of the section or do the action 50px earlier.

here's my code but it will change the opacity from the beginning.

```
var header = $('header');
$(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        var targetHeight =  header.outerHeight();
        var height = header.height();
        var offset = header.offset().top;
        var opacity = (height - scrollTop + offset) / height;
        $('.logo.white').css('opacity', opacity);

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahr3nyfL/1/)

Comment: Check the `scrollTop` value and if it is less than `xxx` don't change the opacity -> https://jsfiddle.net/n0yhuz25/

Comment: I've updated your fiddle. Please check here - https://jsfiddle.net/aalok123/m7exj8su/4/

Comment: Thanks Morpheus and AlokMali, both worked as expected

Comment: You are most welcome brother.

Comment: but it has some problem which the opacity is flickering and its not smooths